# listar, apagar, ou inserir, selecionar matrize em mips

Tags: arquivo, matriz, crud, assembly, mips

estou com umas duvidas a cerca de um trabalho académico em que o professor pede para listar, apagar, inserir e selecionar matrizes.

Se alguém me pudesse explicar como fazer agradecia, segue a baixo os slides do trabalho e o que é pedido, a parte das matrizes já esta feita mas não sei mesmo como fazer a gestão de dados. A vermelho esta o topico em que tenho duvidas

```
.data
prompt:     .asciiz "Digite o nº de linhas para a matriz1 :"
prompt2:    .asciiz "Digite o nº de colunas para a matriz1 :"
prompt3:    .asciiz "Digite o nº de colunas para a matriz2 :"
print1:     .asciiz "Insira os valores da matriz1 : "
print2:     .asciiz "Insira os valores da matriz2 : "
print7:     .asciiz "\t"
print8:     .asciiz "\n"
menu:           .asciiz "1-Multiplicação\n2-Adicão\n3-Subtração\n"
menu2:          .asciiz "1-Ler\n2-Adicionar\n3-Selecionar\n4-Apagar"
opcao:      .asciiz "\nEscolha a opção : "
toWrite:    .asciiz "Hello World was here"
fileName:   .asciiz "C:/Users/DimiHk/Downloads/trabalho.txt"
fileWords:  .space 1024


.text
.globl main

main:
    
    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    
    addi $v0, $0, 4 
    la $a0,menu2
    syscall

    addi $v0, $0, 4 
    la $a0,opcao
    syscall

    addi $v0, $0, 5 
    syscall
    add $t3, $0, $v0 


    beq $t3, 1, ler
    beq $t3, 2, adicionar
    beq $t3, 3, selecionar 
    beq $t3, 4, apagar
    syscall
    
ler:
    li $v0,13           
    la $a0,fileName         
    li $a1,0            
    syscall
    move $s0,$v0        


   li $v0, 14       
move $a0,$s0        
la $a1,fileWords    
la $a2,1024     
syscall


li $v0, 4       
la $a0,fileWords
syscall


    li $v0, 16              
    move $a0,$s0            
    syscall
    j main
    
adicionar:

    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall

    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         
    move $t0, $v0
    
    la $a0, prompt2
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         
    move $t1, $v0
    
    la $a0, prompt3
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall         
    move $t2, $v0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print1      
    syscall
    li $v0, 1
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print8      
    syscall

    li $t3, 0               
    mul $t4, $t0, $t1       
    mul $s5, $t1, $t2       
    mul $t8, $t4, 4         
    j alocacao_matriz1


alocacao_matriz1:
         move $a0, $t8
         li $v0, 9
             syscall
         move $s0, $v0              
         move $t6, $s0              
          j armazena_matriz1

armazena_matriz1:

    beq $t3, $t4, inicializa_matriz2

    li $v0, 5           
    syscall

    move $t5, $v0           
    sw $t5, 0($s0)          

    addi $s0, $s0, 4        
    addi $t3, $t3, 1        
    j armazena_matriz1


inicializa_matriz2:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print2      
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, print8      
    syscall
    
        move $a0, $t8
        li $v0, 9
        syscall
        move $s1, $v0               
        move $t7, $s1               

        move $t3, $zero             

    j armazena_matriz2


armazena_matriz2:

    beq $t3, $s5, menus

    li $v0, 5           
    syscall

    move $t5, $v0       
    sw $t5, 0($s1)      

    addi $s1, $s1, 4    
    addi $t3, $t3, 1    
    j armazena_matriz2

    
selecionar:

apagar:
        
    

menus:

    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    
    addi $v0, $0, 4 
    la $a0,menu
    syscall

    addi $v0, $0, 4 
    la $a0,opcao
    syscall

    addi $v0, $0, 5 
    syscall
    add $t3, $0, $v0 


    beq $t3, 1, multiplicacao
    beq $t3, 2, adicao
    beq $t3, 3, subtracao 
    syscall
    
multiplicacao:

    li $t3, 0           
    li $s4, 0               
    li $s5, 0               
    li $s7, 0               
    mul $t4, $t0, $t2       

    move $s0, $t6           
    move $s1, $t7           
    move $t0, $t7           

    mul $s6, $t1, 4         
    mul $t8, $t2, 4         

    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    j matrix_load

matrix_load:

    
    beq $t3, $t1, print_and_reset
    lw $t5, 0($s0)          
    addi $s0, $s0, 4        

    lw $t9, 0($s1)          
    add $s1, $s1, $t8       

    mul $s3, $t5, $t9       
    add $s4, $s4, $s3       

    addi $t3, $t3, 1        
    j matrix_load

print_and_reset:

    move $a0, $s4
    li $v0, 1               
    syscall
    la $a0, print7
    li $v0, 4               
    syscall
    
    move $s0, $t6

    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    move $s1, $t0

    addi $s5, $s5, 1    
    addi $s7, $s7, 1        
    li $t3, 0               
    li $s4, 0               

    beq $s5, $t4, main
    beq $s7, $t2, mat1_next_row
    j matrix_load

mat1_next_row:
    
    add $t6, $t6, $s6
    move $s0, $t6

    move $s1, $t7
    move $t0, $t7

    li $s7, 0            

    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4            
    syscall
    j matrix_load
adicao:
    bne $t0,$t2,main
    li $t3, 0           
    li $s4, 0               
    li $s5, 0               
    li $s7, 0               
    mul $t4, $t0, $t2       

    move $s0, $t6           
    move $s1, $t7           
    
    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    
    j adicao_matriz

adicao_matriz:
    
    beq $t3,$t1,reseta_valores
    lw $s3,0($s0)
    lw $s4,0($s1)
    add $s6,$s3,$s4
    move $a0, $s6
    li $v0, 1               
    syscall
    la $a0, print7          
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall     
    addi $s0,$s0,4
    addi $s1,$s1,4
    addi $t3,$t3,1
    addi $s5,$s5,1
    j adicao_matriz

 reseta_valores:
    beq $s5,$t4,main
    la $a0, print8    
    li $v0, 4         
    syscall          
    li $t3,0         
    j adicao_matriz
            
subtracao:
    bne $t0,$t2,main
    li $t3, 0           
    li $s4, 0               
    li $s5, 0               
    li $s7, 0               
    mul $t4, $t0, $t2       

    move $s0, $t6           
    move $s1, $t7           
    
    la $a0, print8
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall
    
    j sub_matriz

sub_matriz:
    
    beq $t3,$t1,reseta_sub
    lw $s3,0($s0)
    lw $s4,0($s1)
    sub $s6,$s3,$s4
    move $a0, $s6
    li $v0, 1               
    syscall
    la $a0, print7          
    li $v0, 4           
    syscall     
    addi $s0,$s0,4
    addi $s1,$s1,4
    addi $t3,$t3,1
    addi $s5,$s5,1
    j sub_matriz

reseta_sub:
    beq $s5,$t4,main  
    la $a0, print8    
    li $v0, 4         
    syscall          
    li $t3,0          
    j sub_matriz
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]